# Windows 8.1 EFI partition rebuild not working

Tags: windows-8.1, bootloader, efi, bcd

It all began when I deleted the partition of an old Linux that was dual-booted with Windows 8.1 UEFI. This Linux system was using the Grub2 bootloader and was installed on a secondary disk.

After rebooting grub was thrown in the rescue shell because it probably could not find it's files that were on the deleted partition.

I tired to fix the issue by booting off a Windows 8.1 CD (booted as UEFI) and attempting various things:

- Automatic startup issue fixing from recovery options. This failed.
- Executing `bootrec` with `/fixboot` and `/fixmbr`. This said that it completed, but did not change anything.
- Executing `bootrec /scanos`. This said that there were 0 Windows installations found. As a result `bootrec /rebuildbcb` did nothing useful aswell.
- Manually rebuilding the BCD. Assigned the EFI partition to drive letter V: and deleted the contents of it (it still contained files from grub). Then executed `bcdboot C:\Windows -l de-DE /s V: /f ALL`. This was successful and actually did change booting behaviour, but gave me the error below.

How do I boot into Windows again?

The bootloader error:

```
Your PC Needs to Be Repaired

The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

File:\Windows\system32\winload.exe
Error code: 0xc000000e

You' ll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator.
```

Output of diskpart `list vol`:

DISKPART> list vol

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     F   ESD-ISO      UDF    DVD-ROM     3182 MB  Healthy
  Volume 1     C   850 Pro      NTFS   Partition    237 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    300 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Vertex 4     NTFS   Partition    204 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     E   Garbage      NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy
```

Output of `bcdedit`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
displayorder            {default}
bootsequence            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {1xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
detecthal               Yes
```

Comment: Did you try running Startup Repair again after getting this latest  bootloader error?

Comment: @Karan Yes I tried that, but it still fails. Looking at the logfile `SrtTrail.txt` it does not show any errors. Bottom line says that it succeeded starting the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Using anything that will boot (an Ubuntu live CD, for instance), access your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and rename or delete the directory that holds your GRUB file(s). For instance, if you installed Ubuntu, the files would be in `EFI/ubuntu`; if you installed Fedora, they'd be in `EFI/fedora`. Once you've done this, the firmware won't be able to find GRUB because the pointer in NVRAM will be to a filename that's no longer valid. The firmware should then skip that entry and move on to the next valid one, which should be for Windows.

Comment: As my last step said, I completly deleted all contents of the EFI partition before building the BCD. This results in basically just deleting the "EFI/distro" and modified BCD file, as the bcdboot tool copies all required files to the partition again. I verified this by comparing to a backup of the partition.

Comment: As an additional note: I'm currently able to boot to Windows after installing Debian Jessie with the installer tool on a small partition. So it seems like the BCD is fine or grub just handles it better than the Windows bootloader.